# What happens when a polarized light get reflected by a rough dielectric material?

Tags: optics, polarization

I have a polarized light (lets say p  polarized) which happens to undergo scattering when it is obstructed by a rough opaque dielectric material. What will happen to polarization? Will some part of it becomes s polarized or circularly polarized? I am assuming light is either reflected or absorbed and there is no refraction therefore fresnel equation does not apply (or does it?).

Comment: Depends rather a lot on the index of refraction of the "dielectric."  A dielectric by definition is not opaque if it's not absorbing, so there's always an interference effect. That said, if it's a rough enough surface, the output will be randomly polarized.